# Why am i getting "Trigger's related Job's name cannot be null" error in quartz

Tags: java, scheduling, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I'm getting this error, even though i'm specifying a name, group and description for my job, and in the debugger i can see values for all these fields in the detail variable.

```
JobDetail detail = getDetail();
Trigger newTrigger = getTrigger( detail );
_quartzScheduler.scheduleJob( newTrigger );

JobDetail getDetail()
{
    JobBuilder jb = JobBuilder.newJob( LoadScheduleJob.class );

    jb = jb.withIdentity( JOB_LABEL +"Fred", "Group" );
    jb = jb.withDescription( "DD" );
    jb = jb.usingJobData( SCHEDULEID_MAP_KEY, Integer.valueOf( 22 ) );
    return jb.build();
}

Trigger getTrigger( JobDetail job ) throws ParseException
{
    CronTriggerImpl t = new CronTriggerImpl();//      TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob( job ).
    t.setName( TRIGGER_LABEL + 22 );
    t.setGroup( "GroupJob" );
    t.setCronExpression( "1/7 * * ? * *" );
    return t;
}
```

I believe Job and JobDetail are synonymous...Is that correct?

Comment: Could you show part of the class that is supose to be fired when the trigger is fired.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind.  I see i never got around to assigning the trigger's job

Comment: Please expand on your comment. What was the fix?